# Convert.ToDateTime doesn't work past 09:59?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a C# application I wrote but my `Convert.ToDateTime` doesn't work past 09:59 ?

Here is my code:

```
strDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(0, 11) + " " + arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(13, 7));
```

This is what's in `arr[3]`:

> [20/Feb/2014:14:21:32 +0100]

Its driving me crazy!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the first colon should be there

Comment: I think you are catching the `:` at the end of the date and the time. Please check and see if making the substrings less in length (to exclude the `:`) would get your required behavior

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(x.TrimStart('[').Substring(0, 11) + " " + x.TrimStart('[').Substring(12, 8))` - this is the correct version; And please rewrite this with DateTime.ParseExact();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Substring` is incorrect. This should work (and is more readable):

```
string both = arr[3].Trim('[', ']');
string datePart = both.Substring(0, 11);
string timePart = both.Substring(12);
string dateTimePart = string.Format("{0} {1}", datePart, timePart);
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePart);
```

Or use `DateTimeOffSet.Parse`:

```
DateTimeOffset offset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(dateTimePart);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
string s = "[20/Feb/2014:14:21:32 +0100]";

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"[dd\/MMM\/yyyy\:HH\:mm\:ss zzzz]", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** You are truncating from 13th index for time but in your string Time starts from 12th character

**Solution 1:** You should extract the Time from Index position 12 to 20(12+8)th charactercharacter.

Replace This:

```
arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(0, 11) + " " + arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(13, 7)
```

With This:

```
arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(0, 11) + " " + arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(12, 8)
```

**Suggestion** You need to use `DateTime.ParseExact()` to parse the datetime in required custom format as below:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**Complete Code:**

```
string arr = "[20/Feb/2014:14:21:32 +0100]";
string str=arr.TrimStart('[').Substring(0, 11) + " " + arr.TrimStart('[').Substring(12, 8);
DateTime strDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

with your substring

```
arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(13, 7));
```

you don't get the whole time out of the string [20/Feb/2014:14:21:32 +0100]

you only get 4:21:32 instead of 14:21:32

try

```
arr[3].TrimStart('[').Substring(12, 8));
```